# Unable to send message via masstransit Broker unreachable: guest@localhost:5672/

Tags: c#, docker, .net-core, rabbitmq, masstransit

I'm new to docker.  I created a .net core 5.0 web api project.

**UPDATE**
Originally, I was getting the error below on startup.  I'm currently receiving the error when attempting to send my message.

**Goal:** Send message via masstransit

**Error:**
warn: MassTransit[0]
Retrying 00:00:08.1220000: Broker unreachable: guest@localhost:5672/
MassTransit.RabbitMqTransport.RabbitMqConnectionException: Broker unreachable: guest@localhost:5672/
---> RabbitMQ.Client.Exceptions.BrokerUnreachableException: None of the specified endpoints were reachable
---> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (Connection failed)
---> RabbitMQ.Client.Exceptions.ConnectFailureException: Connection failed
---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (111): Connection refused

I created a **docker-compose** file

```
version: '3.4'

networks:
  poc:

services:
  rabbitmq:
    image: masstransit/rabbitmq:latest
    networks:
    - poc
    container_name: rabbitmq
    environment:
        RABBITMQ_ERLANG_COOKIE: ${RABBITMQ_ERLANG_COOKIE}
        RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER: ${RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER}
        RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS: ${RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS}
    ports:
        - 5672:5672
        - 15672:15672
  webapi:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}webapi
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: WebApi/Dockerfile
    ports:
        - 5100:80
    
  test:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}test
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Test/Dockerfile
    ports:
        - 5101:80
```

In my **startup.cs** on the **WebApi** side...

```
services.AddMassTransit(mt =>
{
    mt.UsingRabbitMq((context, cfg) =>
    {
        cfg.AutoStart = true;
        cfg.Host("rabbitmq");
        cfg.UseRabbitMqMessageScheduler();
        cfg.ConfigureEndpoints(context);
    });
});
```

My **controller**

```
public class OrderController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IBusControl _bus;

        public OrderController(IBusControl bus)
        {
            _bus = bus;
        }

        [HttpPost("api/order")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index([FromBody] Order order)
        {
            try
            {
                Uri uri = new Uri("queue:order-queue");
                var endpoint = await _bus.GetSendEndpoint(uri);
                await endpoint.Send(order);
                return Ok("Success");
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                return StatusCode(500, exception);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

When I run services in *Docker*, I find that `localhost` doesn't work. So I use a check to see if I'm in a container and use the `rabbitmq` hostname (or whatever the host name of your RabbitMQ container is in `docker-compose.yml`.

```
static bool? _isRunningInContainer;

static bool IsRunningInContainer =>
    _isRunningInContainer ??= bool.TryParse(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("DOTNET_RUNNING_IN_CONTAINER"), out var inContainer) && inContainer;
```

Then, in `UsingRabbitMq`:

```
if (IsRunningInContainer)
    cfg.Host("rabbitmq");
```

> A [working example](https://github.com/MassTransit/Sample-ForkJoint) if you need to see how it's all wired up.

Comment: Chris Patterson, I was able to add in the container check.  I'm now getting this error which makes some sense.

Broker unreachable: rabbitmq:5672/
 ---> RabbitMQ.Client.Exceptions.BrokerUnreachableException: None of the specified endpoints were reachable
 ---> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (Connection failed)
 ---> RabbitMQ.Client.Exceptions.ConnectFailureException: Connection failed

Comment: Well, in your docker-compose, you have `rabbitmq3` so...

Comment: Chris, I made this correction, and moved my content to a docker-compose file.  For the sake of testing locally I just added in the cfg.Host("rabbitmq") as you suggested above. (see edits).  this error is still occurring.  I'm relying on the default guest/guest uname/pw.  does this need to be configured somehow?

Comment: What do you see in the logs? Is it still trying to connect to localhost, or is it connecting to `rabbitmq`? Also, change your controller to depend upon `ISendEndpointProvider` instead of `IBusControl` ... Also, if you're specifying those environment variables, are the values changes? If so, you'll need to tell MassTransit what those values are in the .Host() closure.

Comment: I figured out the issue.  I removed the network config setting from my docker-compose file.  Now the messages are sending to the queue.